# How to reboot system into recovery mode in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grub2, recovery-mode

How can I reboot the system into recovery mode? When I googled it, I saw that I should press and hold the F8 key and then I will get into the grub menu,where I can chose recovery mode, but I tried that and it's not working.

Comment: press the shift key (the instructions in the answers to the question linked in comment to your previous post explain how to get into recovery very clearly)

Comment: Wen i press shift key with f8 key,one screen came ..bt it doesn't looks like grub menu. That sceen was like lot of instructions moving fast..it doest stop nd suddenly went to login page

Comment: forget about the F8 key. You just need to press the left shift key...

Answer (score 2):

You should have simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as soon the BIOS is done, keep hitting it to get the timing right. If that don't work try:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> key
- <kbd>Space</kbd> key

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Comment: Wen i press shift key  with f8 key,one screen came ..bt it doesn't looks like grub menu. That sceen was like lot pf instructions moving fast..it doest stop nd suddenly went to login page@liso nd @zanna

Comment: @AnnJerin You may have pressed shift too late. Keep the shift key pressed as soon as it boots, and without F8 (there is no mention of F8 in this answer).

Comment: I did evrything bt no reslt.